# XCode/Swift: how to add a bar with image at the top of view controller

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder

The iOS app I am developing consists in many `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController` and I would like to have a bar with an image (which is a logo of restaurant) at the top of each view controller, like this image shows:

[image]

Which too of the Interface Builder shall I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a titleview in your navigationbar. Any logo is possible. Also Labels and other UI elements. Be sure that you use AspectFit for your UIImageView.

See [Custom title](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-set-a-custom-title-view-in-a-uinavigationbar) for reference

So in short. Declare UIImage, Declare UIImageView. Add image to the imageview. Then add imageview to the titleview:

```
navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Navigation bar and put the image into it.

Comment: but, will the navigation bar override the default back button?

Comment: Since you are customizing the the navigation bar such issues will not be there.

Answer (score 1):

Create baseViewController class and inherit all classes from this.
then in viewDidLoad method of baseViewController, add following line

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Child controller will be like this.

```
class LoginViewController: BaseViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

so you don't need to add navigationItem.titleView in each viewController class.